# is this example of k&r chapter 2 wrong?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
/* squeeze: delete all c from s */
void squeeze(char s[], int c)
{
  int i, j;
  for (i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    if (s[i] != c)
      s[j++] = s[i];
  s[j] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
  squeeze("squeeze", 'z');
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with gcc and ran it, and got a segmentation fault as a result.
Anything wrong with this example?

thanks to men,i have just made a usual mistake.

Comment: You passed a string literal and the functions tries to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example shows that you're trying to apply `squeeze()` to a string literal (`"squueze"`). This is not correct, since string literals are not always modifiable so it's invalid to try 
to modify them. You need to call it with a character array:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   char test[] = "squeeze";

   squeeze(test, 'z');
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```